# When trying to create a Python3.6 virtualenv I get "The executable python3.6 (from --python=python3.6) does not exist"

Tags: python, terminal

I'm inside `desktop/mydirectory` and perform `virtualenv yourenv -p python3.6`.

That returns this error:

```
The executable python3.6 (from --python=python3.6) does not exist
```

Why is this?

Comment: Because the `python3.6` command was not found on your shell path? Pass in the full path instead.

Comment: I followed all the steps to this tutorial: https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/install-django-on-mac-or-linux/ so not sure what else I'm supposed to do Edit: Ok I will try that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Either python3.6 is not installed or not found in your path

Comment: Any idea how I can find the path to python3.6?

Comment: Can you try running the commands "python3 -V" or "python3.6 -V"
Depending on whichever of these work, try "virtualenv yourenv -p python3" or "virtualenv yourenv -p python3.6"
If both doesn't work, try reinstalling python3

Comment: Ah I hadn't installed python3.6.....all fixed now thankyou.